# Yii Use two different tables for login with different RBAC

Tags: php, yii

I want to use two different tables for login. One for users and one for staff login. Currently there is only one table 'users' and I am using yii's built in RBAC and everything is working fine. Now I want to add the second table 'staff' for login without RBAC. So during login it will first check for the username in 'users' table and if it is not there then it will check in the 'staff' table and then check the password. I was able to do the logic for login successfully. But now the problem is RBAC. The "AuthAssignment" table has userid as foreign key of 'users' table, so if the staff id has a corresponding id in 'users' table then the system will provide access according to the role of the 'users' table. How can I avoid it if login is from staff table. Is it possible to give different role for 'staff' table or is it possible to not use role for 'staff' table.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want 2 tables?

Comment: @Naruto        Staff table will have more entry and may or may not have username and password. Also it is used in only one module so I want to separate that.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have one table for logins (because of FK and relationships).

```
[user]

ID | username | password | type
```

Than have staff and users info table with different fields:

```
[staff]

ID | user_id | workstation_id | favorit_tool | ... 

[user_info]

ID | user_id | name | surname | address | ...
```

Than in Yii you can do relations:

```
[userModel]

public function relations() {
    return [
        'stuff' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'stuff', 'user_id', 'condition' => 'type = '.static::TYPE_STUFF],
        'info' => [self::BELONGS_TO, 'user_info', 'user_id',
    ];
}
```